# How to detect if a user exist in a file properties in python

Tags: python

Precisely, I am trying to figure out if a file have the user "TrustedInstaller" in its security user list properties Or obtain the list of users I.e Administrator, users, Other and etc from file

I tried `os.stat(file)`, but doesn't seem to list the list of users within the file.

I am using windows 11 x64 and PEFile (not mandatory).

Comment: Which OS / file system?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stack Overflow, this question needs a lot of work in order to be clear. Please follow the guides in: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
Stack Overflow is not meant to give you the code, you need to provide what you have done. We help you debug and find the answer, not code it for you.